# Error: `call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore`

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## Background Info

I have started developing a backend for an simple App, and I have set up a database class (named `DBDelegate`) that all the files will communicate with. 
In my `AppDelegate.swift` I have this:

```
static public var dbDelegate:DBDelegate = DBDelegate()

private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Its a `static public` so I can access the `dbDelegate` from other files.

In my other files, I have the following to help readability: (because it is a class it will pass by reference)

```
let dbDelegate = AppDelegate.dbDelegate
```

In my `DBDelegate` class:

```
var db = Firestore.firestore()
init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

## Building and Running

When I build my code, it builds fine.

On run, the app promptly crashes with `SIGABRT`.
The error message is:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfiguredException', reason: 'Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore'`

## What I have tried

- I have tried putting a breakpoint on the init function in the `DBDelegate` class. It does not reach the breakpoint.
- I have tried making the all the `dbDelegate` variables `lazy`:

  - I got a compile error for the one in AppDelegate: `lazy must not be used on an already-lazy global`
  - Runtime errors for others: please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore.
- I have tried the following (assigning dbDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
    static public var dbDelegate:DBDelegate!
    private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        dbDelegate = DBDelegate()
        return true
    }
```

- I get Compile error: `Static member 'dbDelegate' cannot be used on instance of type 'AppDelegate'`

Any help would be great!

Edit: I found a janky solution, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to thank @DionzB for suggesting using singletons (which I did). I will reference his/her post in this answer.

Ok, so after some research and playing with breakpoints, I found that my custom class actually executes before the AppDelegate. Knowing such, I created a variable before the following line:

```
static let shared = FirebaseService()
```

the name does not matter, because I/you will not call it, and assign it to `FirebaseApp.configure()`

The FirebaseService class becomes:

```
class FirebaseService: NSObject {
    let constantToNeverTouch = FirebaseApp.configure()
    static let shared = FirebaseService()

    init() {
    }
}
```

Next, you must make sure that FirebaseApp.configure() is no where else in your code. It should not be in the AppDelegate either. Having multiple FirebaseApp.configure()'s crashes the app.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the AppDelegate init method with FirebaseApp.configure() and make sure it loads before any windows are created.

```
override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to create a new singleton for Firebase.

```
class FirebaseService: NSObject {
    static let shared = FirebaseService()

    init() {
         FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}
```

Then you can access everything via shared like:

```
FirebaseService.shared.methodName
```

For configuring in app delegate you would need to call it like:

```
_ = FirebaseService.shared
```

Comment: Thank you for helping make my code clearer, but I still have the error.

Comment: No no you have to use my idea instead of yours, and you will need to call it in App Delegate `_ = FirebaseApp.shared` as I told you. Then in different controllers you will use again this service but every time you must access methods from shared instance.

Comment: I used your idea but `super.init()` does not work because my `DBDelegate` class is the root class. Also did you mean `_ = FirebaseService.shared` in the App Delegate because FirebaseApp has no member shared

Comment: I removed `super.init()`. I said FirebaseService the new class I created not `Firebase` default class

Comment: Verry sorry, but it seems our code still does not work. I am now thinking it may be because the commands are exceuted before FirebaseApp gets a chance to fully init()

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your code are in the wrong order. Make sure your window code are put AFTER the firebaseApp.configure and not before. I was getting the same crash until  I simply placed my window creation codes:  (window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds), etc) after the firebaseApp.configure connection .Just swapped their placement:

```
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let settings =  db.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    db.settings = settings

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = HomeController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue because my pod version it old. So the solution is

1. Check your pods by using command `pod --version`
   If pod the version is old or not the same, CocoaPods needs to update. Use comment `sudo gem install CocoaPods`
2. After it has completed you need to check your pods again use command `pod --version` make sure your pod version is upgraded
3. `cd` to your project directory then use command `pod deintegrate`
   After the command completed then use `pod install`
4. Open your project workspace, build & run