# Failed to get FirebaseApp instance even though I used FirebaseApp.configure()

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, runtime-error

I'm trying to use firebase firestore but keep getting this error:
`Thread 1: "Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore"`
This happens even though I do call `FirebaseApp.configure()` here:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

And I have been using firebase authentication with no problems. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "I'm trying to use firebase firestore but keep getting this error"  Where!?  Have you imported 'Firebase' to AppDelegate?

Comment: it sounds like a race condition. if you are accessing firestore before your firebase app is instantiated you will see this issue.

Comment: It'll be nice if you share the complete code so we can see if you have imported Firebase correctly.

Comment: try to get answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469351/error-call-firebaseapp-configure-before-using-firestore